# Webscraping data from an chart on website that can only be seen when hovering the mouse onto it

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a website here: https://aspren.dmac.adelaide.edu.au/ that I need to web crape info of the chart on it by python. Here is the chart:
[Syndromic Surveillance Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIcph.png) When hovering the mouse onto it, I can see the date and Influenzas Illness Rate on that day. For example: on Oct 24, the rate is 1.04. I would like to webs crape the latest date and rate info from this graph each week. But I inspected the website page and found the date and rate info will only show up when I move the mouse onto it. Does anyone can help me with getting the data??  I have looked into the solutions with similar problems and used multiple ways to solve it,  but I still cannot get it. Thank you for advance for anyone's help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is difficult to do with web scraping, as the data is updated via JavaScript. Instead, it's easier to fetch the data from the site directly and then parse that.

To find out what request has the data you need, you can look on the Network tab in your browser's developer tools. Here is what I saw with Firefox:

[image: Screenshot of Firefox developer tools showing the ASPREN site]

From that, I saw that you can get the data by sending a POST request to the URL `https://aspren.dmac.adelaide.edu.au/c/portal/render_portlet?p_l_id=20734&p_p_id=chartportlet_WAR_chartportlet_INSTANCE_j3c9CC2nTCP9&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_t_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_pos=8&p_p_col_count=11&p_p_isolated=1&currentURL=%2F`. You can fetch this URL from a Python script by using the [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library.

The request returns an HTML page with a script containing the data as a JavaScript object. We need to do a bit of work to make the data readable from Python. Here is my solution:

```
from datetime import datetime
import json

import requests


def fetch_chart_data():
    # Fetch the data from the remote server, and raise an error if there was a
    # network problem or the server returned an error status code.
    result = requests.post(
        "https://aspren.dmac.adelaide.edu.au/c/portal/render_portlet",
        params={
            "p_l_id": "20734",
            "p_p_id": "chartportlet_WAR_chartportlet_INSTANCE_j3c9CC2nTCP9",
            "p_p_lifecycle": "0",
            "p_t_lifecycle": "0",
            "p_p_state": "normal",
            "p_p_mode": "view",
            "p_p_col_id": "column-1",
            "p_p_col_pos": "8",
            "p_p_col_count": "11",
            "p_p_isolated": "1",
            "currentURL": "/",
        }
    )
    result.raise_for_status()

    # Parse the HTML to get the JavaScript data object, and edit it to be valid
    # JSON. This way of doing it is liable to break if the structure of the
    # data or the HTML changes, but it works. Fancier ways of doing it involve
    # using HTML and JavaScript parsers.
    text = result.text
    chart_json = text[text.index("series:[{") + 7 : text.index("})})")]
    for key in ("name", "data", "visible"):
        chart_json = chart_json.replace(key, '"' + key + '"')

    # Convert the JSON data into a Python object. The dates in the raw data
    # are in Unix timestamp format (in thousandths of a second), so convert
    # them into Python datetime objects.
    chart_data = json.loads(chart_json)
    for disease_data in chart_data:
        for data_point in disease_data["data"]:
            data_point[0] = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(data_point[0] // 1000)

    return chart_data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(fetch_chart_data())
```

Comment: Wow. This is simply amazing!! Thank you so much Jack! And thanks to stackoverflow community! This is my first time post a question on stackoverflow, didn't thought I would get great response that fast!!

Comment: @WenqingWu You're welcome! If this was useful, please mark my answer as the accepted answer. :)